# Debugging with webpack-dev-server lists VM files in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack

When using chrome to debug some javascript which was bundled and served with `webpack-dev-server`, the output in the console points to files with names and line numbers that look like this:

`VM17562 playground.js:118453`

I'm guessing that this can be improved using source maps? These should be available somewhere because Chrome claims that there is a `Source Map Detected`.

I have `debug: true` in my `webpack.config.js` file.

Do I need to do anything special to get chrome to use these files so that I get more legible source file / line number output in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [enable Source Maps in Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps#enable_source_maps_in_settings) but it is most likely enabled by default. You can find the sourcemaps in the webpack:// folder on the left of the Source Tab in your dev tools window.

Using the [devtool property](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) in your webpack configuration, you can choose from the following settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Adding `devtool: "cheap-source-map"` to my `webpack.config.js` file gave me proper console sources.